# How can I improve a count query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table with a huge amount of data and a couple of indexed columns, and I need to run a query to count how many records exist with almost duplicate data. Here's what I mean by almost duplicate data: there's a user table with a column for phone numbers, sometimes those numbers come with an extra prefix, but I know that the numbers `CC123456` and `CCX123456` (CC being the country code and X the extra prefix) are the same.

My original idea was to use a subquery, but it ran for 25 minutes before mysql workbench called it quits, so I figured there should be a better way to do this. The query I tried was something like

```
/* CC is once again the country code and X is the extra prefix */
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM users
WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(phone_number) = 13 AND
      phone_number LIKE 'CCX%' AND
      phone_number IN (
          SELECT CONCAT(CC, SUBSTRING(phone_number FROM 3))
          FROM users
          WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(phone_number) = 12 AND
                phone_number LIKE 'CC%'
      );
```

Does anyone know how I could make this better?

EDIT: I ran EXPLAIN on the query and here's the result of that. u1 and u2 are just aliases to the tables and id_store and email are just indexed columns

```
id  | select_type          | table | type    | possible_keys             | key        | key_len | ref  | rows      | Extra
'1' | 'PRIMARY'            | 'u1'  | 'range' | 'id_store,id_store_email' | 'id_store' | '31'    | NULL | '37604'   | 'Using where; Using index'
'2' | 'DEPENDENT SUBQUERY' | 'u2'  | 'range' | 'id_store,id_store_email' | 'id_store' | '31'    | NULL | '4881464' | 'Using where; Using index'
```

Comment: What does the execution plan look like?

Comment: Best you can do is to implement an external counter and put a trigger on that table, which will increment it every time a new record meeting your condition is inserted.

Answer (score 0):

How about doing a self-join?  Something about like this (untested in MySQL):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM users U, users S
WHERE substring(U.phone_number,1,3)='CCX' and substring(S.phone_number,1,2)='CC' and not(substring(S.phone_number,3,1) = 'X')
and substring(U.phone_number,4,10) = substring(S.phone_number,3,10)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a formatted comment than an answer.

Using functions in the where clause like this:

```
where SomeFunction(SomeField) = something
```

will always be slow.  The more records you have to perform the function on, the slower it will be.  You may be able to reduce the number of records if you can figure out a way to do this sort of thing.

```
where field1 = whatever
and SomeFunction(SomeField) = something
```